# Update value in array in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a reducer

```
const initialState = {
    elements: [{"flag": false}, {"flag": false}]
};

const checkReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_CHECK:

            return {...state, //here I want update element by index, that pass in action};
```

I need to update  an existing value in array *elements*, that I get by the index passed in action.
I can do it like this

```
state.elements[action.key] = {"flag": !action.flag}
```

but then I'll change existing state. according to the redux principles, I can't do it.
So I have to use spread operator and change new object. But I don't know how to use it this way.
Tried something like this

```
...state, elements[action.index]: {"flag": !action.flag}]
```

but it isn't worked. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return {
  ...state,
  elements: state.elements.map((element, index) => {
    if (index === action.key) {
      return {"flag": !action.flag}
    }

    return element
  })
}
```

`array#map` will create a new array, and change only the item whose index match `action.key`.

If you find this process tedious, you could use libraries that let mutate your state while keeping the reducer returning new state. One of those is `immer`.